# How to fix this assembly language program

Tags: c++, assembly

When I try to compile this code in Visual Studio, I get error at ':' on line 13, and it says "expected a ')'"

```
#include<stdio.h>

int increase(int x)
{
    int y;
    asm
    (
        " movl %[x], %%eax   \n"
        " add $0x01, %%eax   \n"
        " movl %%eax, %[y]   \n"
        " jmp done           \n"
        " done: nop          \n"
        : [y] "=m" (y) //Error
        : [x] "m" (x)
        : "eax"
    );
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    printf("Original i value = %d\n", i);
    i = increase(i);
    printf("Using the Assembly code: new i value = %d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support `asm`.  It's variation (for 32-bit compiles) uses `__asm`.

Comment: Visual Studio does not support AT&T style ASM. Use Intel style. Also, inline asm is only supported on 32-bit platforms. x64 and ARM need stand-alone source files.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'll try on Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Dude Visual Studio doesn't support this `asm`